# How do I make a timer that when you first join, you have 15m to 5d until banned?

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I'm making a roblox game where Time is Money. I need code that:

1. Randomly chooses between 15 minutes to 5 days (7200 minutes) on top-center.
2. When that timer runs out, you get banned for running out of time.
3. If you leave, your time is paused. Unpaused when they rejoin.

*(Optional: 4. I can't find the font for the text that is usually on alarm clocks.
(I also need to know how to display it on a GUI, (if you find a different approach, tell it to me)))*

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do what you're asking, but you might find more help on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as I'm not sure if many people here are coders. Also, try experimenting a bit before asking directly how to code a project. If you're still having trouble and have tried multiple approaches to your problem, then you should try to get help.